# How to get latest modified file in nested, multiple directories?

Tags: batch-file

This is my folder structure

```
Temp
- Folder ZZZ (Created on 7 Feb)
-- FileA.bak (Created on 7 February)
-- FileB.bak (Created on 8 February)
-- FileC.bak (Created on 9 February)
- Folder B   (Created on 10 Feb)
-- FileD.bak (Created on 10 February)
-- FileE.bak (Created on 11 February)
-- FileF.bak (Created on 12 February)
```

Currently, I'm using the code below to get the latest .bak file recursively.

`FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR /s "D:\Temp\*.bak" /b /O:D') DO SET latestBakFile=%%I`

### Problem

The code above works well when there is only a single subdirectory. In cases when there is multiple sub-directories, it starts to break. E.g., in the folder structure above, getting the latest file always results in `FileC.bak`. The result I expected was `FileF.bak`

**Reasoning to problem**

I did a test with `DIR /s "D:\Temp\*.bak" /b /O:D`, interchanged `/O:D` with `/O:-D` and found that the sub-directories are always sorted in alphabetical order first before sorting the files according to date modified time in the directories. I figured this was the cause.

Is there a way in which I can always get the latest `.bak` file in the `Temp` directory irregardless of which sub-directory the `.bak` file is located in?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "d:\temp" "d:\temp" *.bak /njh /njs /nc /ns /l /is /ndl /ts /s
        ^| 2^>nul sort /r
        ^| cmd /v /q /c"set/p.=&(echo(!.!)"
    ') do echo %%b
```

This code uses `robocopy` command to retrieve the list of the files with a timestamp in ISO order (`yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss`). This list is sorted in reverse order, leaving the newest element in the first position of the list. The piped `cmd` instance will simple read and output only the first line (newer file) of the list to avoid having to process  the full list (all the output of the `sort` command) with the `for /f` command.

Comment: Can you explain more on `cmd /v /q /c"set/p.=&(echo(!.!)"`? In other words, what does `cmd /v /q /c` and `set/p.=&(echo(!.!)` mean?

Comment: @Mark, one problem of the `for /f` is that it is really slow retrieving the output of a command (it does a lot of memory rellocations). To avoid retrieving the full list of files, the output of the previous commands is piped into a `cmd` instance with `echo off` (`/q`), delayed expansion enabled (`/v`) that will execute a line read operation (`set /p`) and will output the readed value (`echo`). So, as the `for` command will only retrieve the output of the last command in the pipe, only one line will be retrieved/processed.